# Grails run test-app with Forked Grails VM exited with error

Tags: grails

The error occur when I run grails test-app on my grails 2.4.2 however run-app is fine.

i am working with grails 2.4.2

The error log is something like this:

```
Failure:  initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
|  java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching grails test target pattern filter from org.junit.runner.Request$1@19535154
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:35)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /home/pinhaoo/grailsworkspace/testing/target/test-reports
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you look at the test-reports provided? It should hopefully show you what failed and why. If that's not enough, you'll need to provide more information than what you have here, this is too sparse to be able to help provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found the solution here: [Grails User archive](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-3-test-app-on-new-app-fails-with-quot-No-tests-found-matching-grails-test-target-pattern--td4652128.html#message4659044). All I had to do was to add the 'given:' keyword to any unit test. Not necessary to all of them, just for one. After that, the command 'test-app' worked fine for me. Apparently, this happens because none of your test classes have any test methods implemented. This is how my test class looks:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import ticketsystem.Theater

@TestFor(Theater)
class TheaterSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        given: "test"
    }
}
```